# How to delete a node if it has no parent node

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTML agility pack to clean up input to a WYSIWYG. This might not be the best way to do this but I'm working with developers who explode on contact with regex so it will have to suffice.

My WYSIWYG content looks something like this (for example):

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p><span><input id="textbox" type="text" /></span></p>
```

I need to strip the empty paragraph tags. Here's how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
if (nodes == null)
    return;

foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    node.InnerHtml = node.InnerHtml.Trim();
    if (node.InnerHtml == string.Empty)
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

However, because the HTML is not a complete document the paragraph tags do not have a parent node and `RemoveChild` will therefore fail since `ParentNode` is null.

I can't find another way to remove tag though, can anyone point me at an alternate method?

Comment: Wrap the whole content into a div, use your current method, then remove the parent? (possibly using something cruder, since it's a lot easier to do)

Comment: Wanted to point out cases like `<p><p></p></p>`. How important are those to cleanup, as well? Advancing through your foreach will check the parent first, find it not empty, then the child, find it empty and delete it, but now the parent is empty but will not be checked again.

Comment: @Oded Cannot assign to node as it's a foreach variable.

Comment: @VladCiobanu I had thought of this one but I was wondering if there was a better way that this to go about it.

Comment: @GuthMD I don't think our WYSIWYG is capable of producing that but I can't rule it out for sure. It's a good point indeed, though I shall cross that bridge after this one! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, first-level elements are children of the document root, so the following code should work:

```
if (node.InnerHtml == String.Empty) {
    HtmlNode parent = node.ParentNode;
    if (parent == null) {
        parent = doc.DocumentNode;
    }
    parent.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

Comment: I had tried `(node.ParentNode ?? doc.DocumentNode).RemoveChild(node)` which hadn't worked so I'd assumed that something like this wouldn't work. Doing it this way instead works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove from the collection, right?

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
if (nodes == null)
    return;

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count - 1; i++)
{
    nodes[i].InnerHtml = nodes[i].InnerHtml.Trim();
    if (nodes[i].InnerHtml == string.Empty)
        nodes.Remove(i);
}
```

Comment: I need to remove it from the document, not just the collection.

Comment: So the another answer is better, are you still using a foreach iteration?